# Azure blob trigger not firing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I have a simple azure blob storage trigger defined and deployed to azure. I want it to log when a file is uploaded in the blob storage container named "mycontainer."

In the Configuration settings I added the value for the connection string of my storage account in the setting named "AzureWebJobsStorage".

To view the logs I  go to  monitor > logs > Filesystem Logs. Afterwards, I upload two files to my blob storage account expecting the name and bytes to be displayed, but no luck. Are there additional things I need to configure for it to work? Are there other spots I can check to make sure the function is listening to the storage container?

Here is my azure function blob trigger.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace resume
{
    public static class MyApp
    {
        [FunctionName("MyApp")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("mycontainer/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also noticing that I get Exceptions in the live metrics that give the following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Queues\Listeners\QueueListener.cs:line 183
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs:line 147
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be caused by a few things:

1. Double check your storage connection string and make sure it's valid (and complete).
2. Ensure that the storage account you are pointing to is NOT of type "BlobStorage" (use General Purpose (V2).  I have heard that non-General Purpose storage accounts don't work for triggers.

If it's not either of these issues, what version of Functions are you using?

Comment: It was type BlobStorage. I upgraded and now it works, thank you!!